How to submit gallery items in one row in sharepoint?
I have an e-commerce store where users submit multiple items and I want to have a cleaner view of which items are for which order, so at the moment each item gets submitted in each row but I would like to see either this submitted all in one row(ofcourse seperated by spaces but without borders, all the same ID therefore). Right now I do add to cart, then I do the patch
ForAll(
    Gallery6.AllItems,
    Patch(
        IT_ecommerce,
        Defaults(IT_ecommerce),
        {
            'Name': ThisRecord.Name,
            'Submition date': DateValue(SubmitionDate),
            'DOB': DateValue(DOB),
            'Home address': ThisRecord.Address,
            'EmployeeNum':Value(EmployeeNum_x0161),
            'ITEM serial number': Value(Item_serial_x0161),
            'PriceBeforeTax': Value(PriceBeforeTax),
            'Item name': {Value: Item_name125}
            
        }
    );
    
);
Clear(col);
ResetForm(form1);
ResetForm(form2);
ResetForm(form3);

So at this moment when i do submit everything works but each item in it's own row, I want it all in one row to seperate orders.
Thank you for your help!

There should be a 'main' orders table that holds the base order data like total cost etc. There you can add additional column which would for example hold a comma separated list of IDs of the items added to the order
